# How to push the onion bulb grow the leaf rather than the root?

Tags: onions

I pant an onion bulb for decorating purpose as below
[image]

It seems that the bulb only grow the roots, not the leaf when I want it to grow the leaf on the top, could you please let me know how to sort it out?

Answer (score 5):

Onions have an annual growth cycle that is controlled by the day length.

Basically, they grow leaves when the day length is increasing and develop the bulb when it is decreasing.

So unless you can completely exclude natural daylight and replace it with artificial light, the answer to the question is is "try again next spring".

Note, there are species of *allium* which are grown as ornamental plants. You might want to check them out (with Google) and buy some of those bulbs next year instead of using an onion from the supermarket!

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the onion, carefully separate the dry part at the tip and open it up a little hole to expose the center to light.

Or if you're more daring, slice a tiny bit off the top.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I did and let's see how it goes

Comment: Good luck! I find it odd that it has this many roots with no leaves, but let's see how it goes in a week.